# Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]' with an index of type 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift

I'm working in Swift 3.0 and I got a problem with my array.
Each line contains a dictionnary with 2 values.

When I want to change this value I have this message:

" Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]' with an index of type 'AnyObject' "

So,

I create "rows"

```swift
var rows: [AnyObject] = ["" as AnyObject]
```

Then I assign a value to rows[0] for have something in my TableView at the start.

```swift
let firstLine: [String : Any] = ["time": time, "Playing": false]
rows[0] = firstLine as AnyObject
```

And my problem is here. When I try to change the values in "rows".

```swift
var i: Int = 0
for i in rows {
rows[i]["playing"] = true
rows[i]["time] = time
}
```

Have a good day guys !

Comment: Why `var rows: [AnyObject]` if you clearly want to store a concrete type - `Dictionary`?

Comment: Hmmm, i'm going to change that for "Dictionnary" alright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't declare your array as `[AnyObject]` because you clearly want to store a concrete type - `Dictionary`. Use instead

```
var rows: [[String : AnyObject]] = [[:]]

let firstLine: [String : AnyObject] = ["time": time, "Playing": false]
rows.append(firstLine)
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer now I know how to streactly declare my array. 
But now my problem is already here with an other error message:

Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' with an index of type '[String : AnyObject]' --------> for i in rows {
            rows[i]["playing"] = true
            rows[i]["time"] = true
        }

Comment: You should have `rows.append(firstLine as [String : AnyObject])` if your dictionary is declared as `[[String : AnyObject]]`. I strongly recommend not mixing the two.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks for your answer. I have exactly it ! I'm looking why i got this error now ^^ Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' with an index of type '[String : AnyObject]'

Comment: @pierreafranck no need to edit my answer since I already edited it - `firstLine` is already of `[String : AnyObject]` type, no need to cast it